# How can update a column by itself on db Level with Entity Framework and Unit of Work?

Tags: entity-framework, unit-of-work, atomic

I'm using Entity Framework and Unit of Work.

I have a decimal column `OrderBalance` in the `Person` table and I have an `Order` table. I want to update `orderbalance` column by itself at the db level to support concurrent order creations.

I want to insert an order and update `OrderBalance` column with atomocity (all or nothing).

```
public override void Create(Order order)
{
        _orderReposiory.Add(order);

        var person = _personRepository.GetById(order.PersonId);
        person.OrderBalance += order.Amount*order.Price;

        _personRepository.Edit(person);

        _unitOfWork.Commit();
}
```

As you can see, '+=' process is on object level. How can I do this on db level without breaking atomicity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using ExeceutSqlCommand with transactionscope and it's work.

```
public class PersonRepository : GenericRepository<Person>, IPersonRepository
  {  
      public void UpdateOrderBalance(decimal amount,long personId)
        {
            Entities.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("Update Person set OrderBalance=OrderBalance+@p0 where id=@p1", amount,personId);
        }
   }
```

I have changed my Create Method to this

```
  public override void Create(Order order)
        {
          using (var scope = new System.Transactions.TransactionScope())
            {
                _orderReposiory.Add(order);
                AddOrderBalancePerson(order);
                _unitOfWork.Commit();
                scope.Complete();
            }
        }



   private void AddOrderBalancePerson(Order order)
    {
        _personRepository.UpdateOrderBalance(order.Amount*order.Price, order.PersonId);
    }
```

`Entities` in `PersonRepository` and `UnitofWork` are using same `Dbcontext`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the same DbContext instance in both repositories. If you do then you can wrap any number of inserts/updates in a transaction which will give you all or nothing. EF statements will automatically enlist in any transaction pending.

```
using (var tran = dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction()) 
{
  // your updates here
}
```